# Why can a compact convex set in $\mathbb{R} ^ n$ be embedded into a standard simplex?

Tags: general-topology

为什么R^n中的紧凸集能嵌入一个标准单纯形?
This is a question asked in "tieba",maybe it will be translate not very good so I post the original Chinese language question.If I break the community's role,I will delete the article later.

Comment: This seems pretty trivial, am I missing something?  Compact sets are bounded, so you can apply a linear transformation that scales it sufficiently small and translates it inside the simplex.  You don't need it to be closed or convex, and the simplex could be replaced by any set with nonempty interior.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge  Thank you sir,I only have a Higher school education and it's too hard for me...Maybe it's too simple for masters.But you know in china we don't have a good community for different level of math lovers.Maybe my English is not very well....Thank you for answer my question,you are welcome.